# to prevent copy sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel

I created an excel file about costing a metal desking frame, it consist of ***several worksheets***, there is one specific worksheet - a template - where the user can enter data - but this sheet must not be duplicated as it would mess up the program, I protected the sheet but when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key at the same time mouse  dragging the sheet to the right it ***duplicated the sheet!*** while protect workbook completely freezes all worksheets! I want to prevent copy (duplication) only on one sheet (the template). How can I do this

also How do I prevent this specific sheet from being accidentally (or intentionally) deleted?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is lock/unlock cells as required, and then enable worksheet protection.  Passwords are optional but recommended to prevent accidental unlocking.

An important thing to note before going any further is that **there is no *fail-safe* way to protect an Office document** (against neither accidental nor intentional abuse or distribution).  Even Office document passwords are easily defeated.

If you are this concerned about this data, you need to make sure that you are backing it up regularly, and automatically, and keep several versions of backups... (not just the most recent!)

### Protecting a worksheet from changes

When you protect a worksheet, all cells are locked by default, which means that they cannot be edited. To enable cells to be edited while leaving only some cells locked, you can unlock all the cells and then lock only specific cells and ranges before you protect the worksheet. You can also enable specific users to edit specific ranges in a protected worksheet.

Try this an an example of the most basic form of protection:

1. Make a backup copy of your workbook before proceeding.
2. Click the `Review` tab, and then click **Protect Sheet**.

   [image: img]
3. For now, just ignore the check boxes at the bottom of the `Protect Sheet` window. Choose a password and enter it where prompted.  (Do **not** use a password that you use for other things.)

   [image: img2]
4. Click OK.  Enter the password a second time and click OK again.  The worksheet is now protected.

At this point, experiment to see if you are able to make the changes you were concerned about, such and duplicating cells with "Ctrl+Drag".

This is the default setting for protection.  You'll notice that you can't use any of the cells at all, even for "legitimate" purposes, however this can be easily rectified too (with the password!).

---

### Removing workbook protection

When you want to re-enable changes to the worksheet:

1. Click `Unprotect Sheet` on the `Review` tab.

   [image: img3]
2. Enter the password you previously set.

   [image: img4]

...I *literally* already forgot the password I had set, so the unlocking request was denied:

[image: img5]

It's okay, I made a backup first and had it stored in a safe location.

<sup>(Actually, it was a test workbook, and even if it wasn't, I could bypass password protection on any Office document in under 5 minutes.  Hence the earlier warning...)</sup>

---

### Protecting only certain areas or certain activities

In most cases, it's not feasible to have the sheet 100% protected at all times, effectively rendering it "read-only" and non-interactive.  (If it were necessary, you're better off to print the worksheet and hand out *ultra-safe paper copies*.)

Protection can be customized in numerous ways, the most common being unlocking only the sections that the user needs to be able to change.

In the example below, I protect the whole worksheet (since cells are set to "Locked" by default) with the exception of the 2 cells that require data entry.

[image: Animated Screenshot]

Personally I like to always shade the unlocked cells a different color, so that it's obvious to the users which cells they can/can't use.

---

There are too many options to go into them all here, but below are links some of the many sites with more information and examples about Excel workbook ad worksheet security, protection, and other safety concerns:

- Office.com : **[Protection and security in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protection-and-security-in-excel-be0b34db-8cb6-44dd-a673-0b3e3475ac2d)**
- Office.com : **[Protect a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) (Excel)**
- Office.com : **[Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a#__toc296590516)**
- Newco.co : [**Excel 365: How to Protect Cells in a Shared Worksheet**](https://shift.newco.co/excel-365-how-to-protect-cells-in-a-shared-worksheet-8764587e41f0)
- MSDN :  **[Password protect workbooks and worksheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-password-protect-workbooks-and-worksheets-c89fc69d-2d96-4324-8b9d-3076f44cccc9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) (Video)**